# Как задать комбинации клавиш для программ в windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Как задать комбинации клавиш для открытия таких программ как google chrome, командная строка и т.д. в windows 10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У ярлыков - значков программ, если открыть свойства правой кнопкой мыши есть раздел - быстрый вызов, там можно задать сочетание клавиш для быстрого вызова. Самый простой способ.

Comment: А что с максимизацией/минимизацией окон ?